# What does .+= (dot plus equal) in scala mean?

Tags: scala

I have code that looks like
x.=+y
where x is of `ArrayBuffer[String]` type and `y` is a string

Comment: Nothing special, it is just a method on that class. Particularly it appends  an element to the array. Instead of asking a question for knowing what a method does you should check the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/). - BTW, anyone which calls that method with a dot is a psychopath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/operators.html -- in Scala, operators are methods, and methods can be invoked with or without `.` in front of them (between the instance and the method identifiers).

Also see docs for ArrayBuffer, which says `+=` is an alias for `addOne` (or "append to end"): https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html

So this method adds a String `y` to the end of `x` (which is mutable).

```
scala> val x = ArrayBuffer("1", "3")
x: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer(1, 3)

scala> val y = ""
y: String = ""

scala> x.+=(y)
res1: x.type = ArrayBuffer(1, 3, "")

scala> x
res2: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer(1, 3, "")

// Add another string using a space, omitting the dot. Same thing
scala> x += "another string"
res3: x.type = ArrayBuffer(1, 3, "", another string)
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I misspoke. I will edit my answer, thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does scala have so many syntax for the same functionality? Having too many choices isn't always a good thing.

Comment: I think it is to allow easy creation of certain libraries that are more readable, such as Scalatest WordSpecs (where methods like "can", "in", and "should" appear with spaces around them just like in an English sentence). The following official doc on method invocation discourages other arbitrary uses of this kind of syntax, since, with small changes, it can easily result in compiler errors and ambiguity https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html